# Cant access complex qvector's methods

Tags: qt, containers, qvector

I have a data structure looking like this:

```
QVector<QHash<QPair<int, int>, QVector<double> > > * wow = new QVector< QHash<QPair<int, int>, QVector<double> > >(4);
```

When i write `wow->at(0).keys();`
it works fine, but when i write `wow[0].keys();` i receive an error saying the following :

> 'class QVector, QVector > >' has no
>   member named 'keys'
>        wow[0].keys();
>               ^

I will need to use methods that require not only read-only access and i dont understand why this happens.Can you please help me and how should i access the Qhashe's methods in not a read only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `wow[0].keys()`, with `wow` being a pointer, it returns the first object pointed to, like an array. It basically transforms into a dereference of the pointer, like this: `wow->keys()`. Since a `QVector` doesn't have a `keys` method, the compile fails.

If, instead, you want to get element `0` from your vector, you would either use `wow->at(0).keys()` or `(*wow)[0].keys()`. First dereference, then use the subscript operator.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks a lot!